# Time complexity of this recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, master-theorem

```
class Solution {
    
    public:
        bool wordBreak(string s, vector<string>& wordDict) {
            bool rtnVal = false;
                
            wbRecursion(s, 0, wordDict, rtnVal);
            return rtnVal;
        }
    
    private:

        void wbRecursion(string s, int index, vector<string>& wordDict, bool& rtnVal) {
            
            if (index == s.size()) {
                rtnVal = true;
                return;
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < wordDict.size(); i++) {
                if (index + wordDict.at(i).size() - 1 < s.size() &&
                    s.substr(index, wordDict.at(i).size()) == wordDict.at(i)) {
                    
                    wbRecursion(s, index + wordDict.at(i).size(), wordDict, rtnVal);
                    if (rtnVal == true) return;
                    
                }
            }
            
            return;
            
        }
     };
```

I know that the above code is not the optimal solution, but I am curious as to how to find the big O time complexity.

How can we find the time complexity using the master method?

```
T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)
```

Comment: You ask about the master theorem, but you've not yet written down the recurrence relation for the time complexity. Why don't you start there? Note also that you'll probably have to make some assumptions about the distribution of length of words in the word list. Note that the time complexity is at best exponential because if you have the dictionary containing the two words "a" and "aa", it'll take exponential time to fail the input string that is "aa....aaab" where there's n "a"s.

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that the master theorem can help you here. In the very specific example of exponential behavior I gave in my first comment, the recurrence relation would be T(n)  = T(n-1) + T(n-2), about which the master theorem says nothing.